# Programmatically add child to dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

How do I programmatically add a child to `dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane`?
The reference guide only has a declarative example - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane.html.

`ScrollablePane` Doesn't seem to have an `addChild` method. I tried using `placeAt` on the child widget and passed in the `containerNode` of the `ScrollablePane`. That doesn't work either.

The following declarative code works. I'm not able to do it programmatically. Specifically, I cant figure out how to add `RoundRectList` under the `ScrollablePane`.

```
<div id="home" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-props='selected:true'>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='label:"Title", fixed:"top"'>
        <span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
                data-dojo-props='icon:"mblDomButtonWhiteSearch"'></span>
        <span id="refreshButton" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton"
                  data-dojo-props="label: 'Exit'"
                  style="float:right;"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollablePane" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" >
    <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory">Menu</h2>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 1", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 2", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 3", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 4", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 5", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='label:"Item 6", moveTo:"#", transition:"slide", onClick:openScreen' />
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like

```
this.ScrollablePane.domNode.appendChild(RoundRectList.domNode);
```

before this, you need to construct RoundRectList

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , seems dojox exp missed implementation of this last ,
so you can workaround this issue by using the `place` methode of `dojo/dom-construct` module , so after creating you element , just place it's domNode inside the scrollpane's containers node as below code . (here I just affect the `id="scrollpane"` to the ScrollablePane and get it's reference using `dijit/registry` module )

```
var rectList = new RoundRectList();
domConstruct.place(rectList.domNode,registry.byId("scrollpane").containerNode, 'last');
```

you can see a sample Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/xosmvhL8/6/)

Comment: Will this establish the parent-child relationship only between the dom objects or will the same be established between the dojo objects too? I mean if we do getChildren() on the scrollpane dojo object, will it return rectList as one of the children?

Comment: Yes for sur , it will return the created RoundRectList  as an object child in the array's childeren .

Comment: does this help or still have probleme :)

Comment: Haven't had a chance to check this. Will check and post back.

Comment: `domConstruct.place(...)` didn't work. I don't think that is different from the `placeAt(..)` method I've mentioned in the question. Perhaps you can update your fiddle to create the Scrollable pane programmatically similar to how you are creating RoundRectList? For now, I've gone with `dijit/_TemplatedMixin` to create the basic structure and then have add list items programmatically.